# Why isn't my state correctly mapped to props in Redux?

Tags: reactjs, react-redux

I created this component:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';

export class Todos extends Component {
  render() {
    //todo remove
    console.log('testing this.props.todos', this.props.todos);

    //todo remove
    debugger;

    return (
      <div>hello from todos</div>
    );
  }
}

const mapStateToProps = function (store) {
  return {
      todos: store.todos
  }
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(Todos)
```

I am using Redux and this is the reducer:

```
const initialState = {
  todos: [
    {
      name:'first todo'
    }
  ]
}

const Todos = (state = initialState, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case "ADD_TODO":
      var newState = Object.assign({}, state, {todos: [...state.todos, action.data]});
      return newState;
    default:
      //todo remove
      debugger;
      return state;
  }
}

export default Todos;
```

For some reason the `this.props.todos` is undefined and my state is not mapped to my props correctly. How can I hook up the Redux store to my component?

Comment: Can you log store in mapStateToProps and see what you get?

Comment: it is all good now see below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you're not passing the store correctly down to your components! If you want to use `connect` to connect your component to the global state, you have to use the [`<Provider>`](https://github.com/reactjs/react-redux/blob/master/docs/api.md#provider-store) component provided by [`react-redux`](https://github.com/reactjs/react-redux/). So, first you create your store with `createStore` as you've done, then pass it into the provider:

```
import store from './store.js';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux'; 

const App = () => (
  <Provider store={store}>
    <Todos />
  </Provider>
);

ReactDOM.render(
  <div className="container">
    <App />
  </div>
, document.getElementById('root'));
```

Notice how the `<Provider>` is used to *provide* the store and make it available for your `connect` calls. Also, `<Todos>` shouldn't take any props. Also, your import:

```
import { Todos } from './components/todos.jsx';
```

Is wrong. Your `todos.jsx`, you're exporting the `connect`ed component like this, as the default export:

```
export default connect(mapStateToProps)(Todos)
```

So you have to *import the default instead*:

```
import Todos from './components/todos.jsx';
```

Comment: Should it not render the App instead of the div.container?

Comment: @bierhier Yeah, My bad. Edited

Comment: I took your suggestions but the store is still not injected into the Todos component

Comment: @bierhier Looks like you're importing wrong! Do `import Todos from '...'` - You're exporting the injected component as the default, not as a named export!